# Emoji in HTML email generated by Python Appear Distorted in Gmail

Tags: python, gmail, html-email, emoji

I am using a Python script to generate HTML emails that include emoji. When those emails go out, they look correct (the same as they did in the Python source) in the iOS and macOS built-in email client apps, but they look incorrect in Gmail's web interface. Most emojis appear correctly in both, but here are some examples next to images of how they wrongly appear for me in gmail:

️‍ [image: gmail pride flag]

☀️ [image]

⚾️ [image]

Again, the vast majority of emoji from my Python source file are appearing correctly in gmail... not sure what's wrong with these few. They are not being generated any differently than the rest. You can see the full HTML email with the emoji here:
https://us20.campaign-archive.com/?u=e007f7f6b60018de9365a7241&id=cd55fbf320

Comment: There might be a few where Gmail doesnt recognise and can not render?

Comment: @Syfer Nope, these all exist within gmail on their own. Something about the process of generating them is messing up gmail whereas it doesn't mess up mail.app.

Answer (score 0):

First, emoji appear differently depending on the system interpreting them. I'm not sure if that clears things up for you. For examples, see [Emojipedia on the rainbow flag](https://emojipedia.org/rainbow-flag/)

As an alternative, you can insert emoji via HTML code (find out the corresponding HTML code from https://unicode-table.com/en/1F308/):

```
<p>Rainbow Flag: ️‍ </p>
<p>via HTML code: &#127987;&#8205;&#127752;</p>
<p>Baseball: ⚾</p>
<p>via HTML code: &#9918;</p>
```

Which outputs on Gmail App (Android 6.0):

[image: Emoji output on Gmail App on Android 6]

The rainbow flag in both cases doesn't seem to work well with Gmail - perhaps the only option there is to just use a rainbow itself (flag-less), or an icon.